# Automatically set up github private ssh key on GCP VMs

Tags: google-cloud-platform, ssh, private-key

I want to use GCP Spot VMs to run experiments and want to have a startup scrip that automatically sets up my ssh private key and clones from my github repository.

On GCP they have a page about [adding ssh keys to VMs](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/connect/add-ssh-keys) through metadata, however I think the purpose of that is allowing different users to connect to that VM and not allow the VM itself cloning from github.

How can I automatically set up my github ssh private key on a GCP VM using the startup script? I don't think copying my private ssh key on the startup script and writing it in the `~/.ssh/` directory would be good practice for this? Should I somehow write another script that upon VM creation uses `scp` to transfer my private key there from my local file system?

Comment: You can store the key in secret manager, allow the SA assigned to those VMs access to that and then use the script to copy the key from secret manager into your VM

Comment: The workflow I decided to use is uploading my repository on a gcp bucket and downloading it in the startup script